# Too many fetch-failures

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, hdfs

I am executing my `MapReduce` program on a `Multinode` cluster with 3 nodes. While executing I am getting the error `"Status:failed Too many fetch failures"` after MAP 100% was reduced to 16%, so why am I getting this error?

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for the error could be DNS issues, http threads on the mapper side or JVM bug that cause connections to get map outputs fail. Please look at this http://archive.apachecon.com/na2013/presentations/27-Wednesday/Big_Data/14:45-7_Deadly_Hadoop_Misconfigurations-Kathleen_Ting/HadoopTroubleshootingApacheCon.pdf. You can find solution on slide number 24.

Hope this helps